# How to implement a basic Lua function in Conky?

Tags: function, debugging, lua, customization, conky

I am trying to add a function to my Conky which prints the length of a string for debug purposes. The code, inside a file called `test.lua`, is pretty trivial:

```
function test(word)
return string.len(word)
end
```

...and I load it like this. In my `conky.config` section I have:

```
lua_load = '/home/xvlaze/test.lua',
lua_draw_hook_pre = 'test'
```

...in the `conky.text` section I have:

```
${lua test "fooo"}
```

...where `test` is the name of the function and `fooo` the string to test.

The expected result should be a printed 4 in Conky, but instead of that I get:

```
conky: llua_do_call: function conky_test execution failed: /home/xvlaze/test.lua:2: attempt to index a nil value (local 'string')
conky: llua_getstring: function conky_test didn't return a string, result discarded
```

I have browsed through the [documentation](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki), but I can't find anything. Does anybody know where the failure is?

Comment: Frankly calling your parameter `string`, just the same as the regular `string` library can't really end well.

Comment: In this case it even should works. But yes. Its bad idea.

Comment: Updated. Looks worse.

Comment: @xvlaze Is that your entire script? It looks like you have a variable named `string` that is overriding the string library (maybe you did `string = 'this'`)?

Comment: @DavisDude yes, that's my whole script.

Comment: UPDATE: found the solution and wrote a little explanation. I'll update when I can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Several guidances on how to implement functions in Conky:**

- First of all: YOU MUST USE `conky_` BEFORE YOUR FUNCTION'S NAME. 
  Otherwise, you will get the following error when running your Conky:

  ```
  attempt to call a nil value
  ```
- Secondly: YOU MUST ALWAYS RETURN A VALUE. 
  I don't mind repeating it - it is *crucial*. Otherwise, you will get:

  ```
  function foobar didn't return a string, result discarded
  function_result
  ```

  ...*in your terminal*, and your Conky will be left empty of values related to your extra code. Nothing will be printed regarding your function.
- Last but not least: YOU MUST ALWAYS CALL YOUR FUNCTION LIKE:

  ```
  lua_load = '/path/to/function.lua',
  -- Whatever content...
  ${lua function_name function_parameter1 function_parameterN} -- In case you use more than one parameter.
  ```

In summary, a dummy function template could be:

- **MAIN FILE (conky.conf):**

  ```
  conky.config = {
      -- Whatever content... Lua styled comments.
      lua_load = '/path/to/function.lua',
  }

  conky.text = [[
      # Whatever content... In this section comments are started with '#'!    
      ${lua function_name parameter}
  ]]
  ```
- **FUNCTION FILE:**

  ```
  function conky_function_name(parameter)
      -- Whatever content... Remember this is Lua, not conky.text syntax. Always use '--' comments!
      return whatever -- No return, no party. A function MUST always return something!
  end
  ```

Comment: not working right now.is there anything missing?? should `function.lua` be executable?